# php string separate function

Tags: php

In my project a file contains content like

```
&lbl1=Mount Olympus - 24" long x 48" wide - Oil on canvas&prc1=725&sold1=&

&lbl2=Edgartown Marsh 1 - oil on canvas (matted unframed) size: 5 ½" x 5 ½"&prc2=425&sold2=SOLD&
```

and so and so..

I need to display 
`Mount Olympus - 24" long x 48" wide - Oil on canvas`,`725`
and so and so

is it possible?

i have first read the content from that file and then tried to explode with `&` ie `$arrayNewLine=explode("&",$newLine);`

But it's not my result.

Des anyone know this?

Comment: could you please post your result? you can print it with `debug($arrayNewLine);`

Comment: @Daren: `debug`? Not aware of that function.... don't you mean `var_dump`? Or `print_r`? And what do you think the result is? He's splitting it on ampersands..you can do that in your head.

Answer (score 2):

That looks like a URL query string. Try [decoding it](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)?

Answer (score 2):

You can do with [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and [parse_str()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php)

```
    $data=file_get_contents('finename.ext');

    parse_str($data,$parsed_data);

    print_r($parsed_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

The [parse_str](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) function is what you're after.

Alternatively, you could iterate like so:

```
$labels = array();

foreach (explode('&', $newLine) as $item) {
    list($name, $value) = explode('=', $item);
    $labels[$name] = $value;
}
```

Now you have an indexed array of labels. If you want all of the values as a string, try

```
implode(', ', $labels);
```

Good luck!