# How to display a string between two string from a text in PHP?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php string separate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496416/php-string-separate-function)

My string is

```
&lbl12=Bourne Pond II – 30" long X 36" wide - Oil on canvas&prc12=1250&sold12=SOLD&
```

I need to display the text between `&lbl12=` and `&prc12` ie:

> Bourne Pond II – 30" long X 36" wide - Oil on canvas

How can I do this?

Comment: This seems to be [an exact duplicate of your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5496416/php-string-separate-function).

Comment: Do you want to extract the text between `&lbl12=` and `&prc12` (`Bourne Pond II – 30" long X 36" wide - Oil on canvas`)?

Answer (score 0):

```
"&lbl12=".$myvar1."&prc12=".$myvar_2."";
```

do you mean something like this?

also you can urlencode your string after;

```
$string  = urlencode("&lbl12=".$myvar1."&prc12=".$myvar_2."");
```